Mongo DB - how does re-connection works internally?
In my spring boot application, at the startup, I am connecting to mongo db using MongoClient and using MongoCredential.createPlainCredential and thus supplying user-name and password.
Password is being fetched from hashicorp vault using rest call and supplied to mongoCredential.
The task, I am trying look for is - how can I update the password in the Mongoclient bean when password has rotated in the hashicorp vault ?
Before achieving this, I want to understand how mongo db is using the password when the mongo connection is break down in the running application.
using these mogo dependencies

mongodb-driver-sync - 4.6.1

mongodb-driver-core - 4.6.1


Steps I performed as below

app-started and mongo db connection established

application working ok

I disconnected from network, so mongo db connection dropped

can see error in the logs (expected)

re-connected to network,
mongo-db is connecting back automatically and see opened connection (org.mongdb.driver.connection) but I don't see it's using password or how do I know it's using password to reconnect or some token? At this time of reconnection, I don't see, debug point going into the MongoClient.


Once I know this, then only I will be able to update MongoClientBean and supply rotated password.
I read this: Update MongoClient Credentials at runtime
and mainly this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-3896 which closed with a comment - "this was closed because we're converging on an OIDC-based solution to credential rotation."
I am thinking, does my mongo java driver already using OIDC based approach for connection and using password only at very 1st connection and then all the subsequent re-connection is based on the token?
if that's the case, then I don't have to care about updating MongoClient bean with rotated password?

Mongo driver authenticates once a TCP socket is open and is responsible to keep the pool of open sockets. Once the socket is closed, the driver attempts to re-connect / reauthenticate. OIDC is available from v7 for enterprise edition only. Specs are here https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/auth/auth.md.

Latest java driver supports OIDC authentication. For not OIDC authentication, you should recreate a client with new credentials

Thanks for your answer. One qq - when driver is attempting to re-connect/re-authenticate, does it carrying the original MongoClient bean created with initial password at app start up ?   If that's the case, then If a password has changed in vault then MongoClient bean needs to update with new password else the re-connect will fail ? Is that correct understanding ?

for OIDC, it will attempt to use new one (from calling callback or env variables), for non OIDC - it will use old ones

ok thanks. I am definitely having non OIDC. In that case, I am thinking, what is the best approach to update MongoClient bean with new password ( how do I know when to update the MongoClient bean ) so that, re-connect always carries the bean with latest password ?

the only option I'm aware about is to analyze exception and if it's auth exception - then try to recreate a client

Thanks again. I am able to figure out how to update the bean. I have written a custom bean and has got a method  "update" with @Scheduled. The time is set to little more than the time setup for cred update in hashicorp. this method make rest api call and fetch latest password from hashicorp and then uses reflection to update password attribute of MongoCredential object.

it may work in some scenarios, but mongoClient settings are designed to be immutable, so do not be surprised if in some cases your hack won't work

Yes, agree. OIDC is the ideal approach. Do you know if we can attach any listener to mongo client and as we get disconnect event, then refresh mongo client bean ?

possibly SDAM events,  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/v4.6/fundamentals/monitoring/#server-discovery-and-monitoring-events

SDAM events will give the same result as just error caching, since as long as you receive an event with broken cluster state, then you will receive the same error
